# Is it possible to restore a file saved on a live-USB?

Tags: live-usb, 17.04, data-recovery

I booted from a live-USB of Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 and saved a document with Libre Office to the home folder of the live-USB.

I saved the document and was just about to upload it to the cloud when I accidently touched my finger to the USB device. This caused the system to crash. I had to shutdown the computer using a hardware button.

Is there any chance at all that I can restore this document?

Comment: Did you create the live USB with a writeable casper-rw or home-rw file or partition?  If not, then what you saved was in memory, and not restorable.

Comment: @ubfan1 No, it was created in a normal way, with Etcher.

Comment: It depends on where you saved the file. If you saved it on a partition in some other drive, for example the internal drive, and the buffers were flushed before the system crashed, yes. Otherwise no. I am afraid, that you will not be able to restore the file.

Comment: @sudodus As OP says, I saved it in the home folder of the live-USB.

Comment: Unfortunately the file disappeared, when the computer was shut down. (I only wanted to add some details , that might be useful in the future for somebody reading this thread.)

Comment: Don’t touch a live USB! Magicrescue, scalpel, foremost can recover your precious file:):):)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible because you boot the pc via removable disk and when you remove the pen drive all the files and setting will reset..

Comment: Correct although to be precise it is not a matter of removable drive. The problem is the files were in RAM and never written to any disk.